# Why does this SQL stored procedure require that a temp table be created for it to work (return results)?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, syntax, informix

IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.50.FC6

I was working on a small stored procedure that would take name fields from a table and parse them into "user names" with a maximum of 8 chars.

This is the code I was trying:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE build_jics_user (pid INT)
    RETURNING CHAR(8) AS username;
    SELECT LOWER((SUBSTR(firstname,0,1))||(SUBSTR(lastname,0,7))) username
    FROM id_rec
    WHERE id = pid;
END PROCEDURE;
```

The error returned when executed is:

```
  659: INTO TEMP table required for SELECT statement.
Error in line 5
Near character position 15
```

I don't understand what the point of summoning a temporary table is, and I also couldn't find any similarly simple examples online that would work without error.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to say is this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE build_jics_user (pid INT)
    RETURNING CHAR(8);
    DEFINE username CHAR(8);
    SELECT LOWER((SUBSTR(firstname,0,1))||(SUBSTR(lastname,0,7))) INTO username
      FROM id_rec
      WHERE id = pid;
    RETURN username;
END PROCEDURE;
```

... and execute it like this:

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE build_jics_user(42);
```

**UPDATE**

If the purpose of this is to be a function, where it's required inside some other SQL, then you might do the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION jics_user(fname VARCHAR(255), lname VARCHAR(255))
    RETURNING CHAR(8);
    RETURN LOWER(SUBSTR(fname,0,1) || SUBSTR(lname,0,7));
END FUNCTION;
```

... and execute it like this:

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname, jics_user(firstname, lastname) AS jics_user, ...
  FROM id_rec;
```

There's no real technical difference between a PROCEDURE and a FUNCTION, it's more an assertion as to how it's used.

Comment: Thanks - kind of new to creating procedures &| triggers on Informix

Comment: Happy to help. If you wanted to use this as a function in a query that was already reading your id_rec table, then this is a very inefficient way of doing it. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

This [seems to be per design](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.gsg.doc/gsg110.htm) (which must be accounting for the absence of the *'similarly simple examples online'*). Apparently, whatever data you are pulling with a SELECT statement in a stored procedure, you cannot return them directly. You should store them either in a temporary table or in variables for later use.

It is likely that your SELECT statement should look like this

```
SELECT LOWER((SUBSTR(firstname,0,1))||(SUBSTR(lastname,0,7))) INTO username
FROM id_rec
WHERE id = pid;
```

Comment: Most probably a variable in this case as the function only returns a single value

Comment: Thanks! In fact I can now see what is happening in that procedure (which seems to be a function indeed in this case). Updated the answer with a suggestion.