# sql error (-659) into temp table required for select statement

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, informix

I try to create a simple stored procedure which should return a data set as a result of select statement. like this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE rr_reward()

SELECT a.emp_num,a.emp_name
FROM emp_data a
WHERE a.active_code = 1

END PROCEDURE
```

---

but I get the following error:

> sql error (-659) into temp table required for select statement

Comment: Is this question regarding MySQL server? And witch version of the DBMS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this SQL stored procedure require that a temp table be created for it to work (return results)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343187/why-does-this-sql-stored-procedure-require-that-a-temp-table-be-created-for-it-t)

Comment: @juergend : I tried as answered in that question but i get this error :`a subquery returned not eaxctly one row`

Comment: I have not used Informix in ages, but think that to return multiple rows you have to actually look with multiple returns. See http://dbaspot.com/informix/133651-simple-question-cant-find-answer.html

Comment: just I don't want to use loops !!

Answer (score 1):

The error `a subquery returned not exactly one row` is because your query returns a set, not a single row, which [the answer in the linked question assumes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7343187/14750).

Although the thrust of the question is unrelated to your issue, [the very fine answer given by Jonathan in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14988893/14750) shows the structure of a stored procedure that will do what you require.

Basically, you define a `ROW TYPE` that corresponds to your `emp_num` and `emp_name` columns, then RETURN your results as a `MULTISET` of that type.

But I must be honest, I can't see what rationale there is for an SP to do this. A `VIEW` along the lines:

```
CREATE VIEW active_emp (emp_num, emp_data)
  AS SELECT emp_num, emp_name
       FROM emp_data
       WHERE active_code = 1;
```

seems more logical and practical.

Answer (score 1):

Check the manual for "return with resume" , they do the magic...

Example 1)
Which is simpler...

```
CREATE FUNCTION teste_p2( pParam CHAR(100) DEFAULT '%') RETURNING CHAR(20) AS tabname
  DEFINE vSql CHAR(500);
  DEFINE vTab CHAR(20);
  FOREACH select tabname into vTab
    from systables where tabname like pParam
    RETURN vTab WITH RESUME;
  END FOREACH; 
END FUNCTION;
```

Example 2)
More sophisticated

```
CREATE FUNCTION teste_p1( pParam CHAR(100) DEFAULT '%') 
RETURNING CHAR(20) AS tabname
  DEFINE vSql CHAR(500);
  DEFINE vTab CHAR(20);
  LET vSql='select tabname from systables where tabname like ? ';
  LET vTab='';
  PREPARE sts1 FROM vSql; 
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR sts1; 
  OPEN cur1 USING pParam;   
  LOOP 
    FETCH cur1 INTO vTab ; 
    IF SQLCODE = 100 THEN exit; END IF;
    RETURN vTab WITH RESUME;
  END LOOP; 
  CLOSE cur1; 
  FREE cur1;
  FREE sts1;
END FUNCTION
```

Then you call like this:

```
select * from table(teste_p2('systab%')) as t(column);
```

If you need return more fields... just add them at the RETURNING declaration and RETURN WITH RESUME.